# multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter conflict issue

Tags: spring-security, filter

I'm building an application that will need to handle two types of authentications, so i did this

```
@Autowired
UserService userService;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    // Md5PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());// .passwordEncoder(encoder);
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access_denied").and().csrf().disable();
}

@Override
protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return (UserDetailsService) userService;
}

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public static class ApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    AuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilter;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint customAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    TokenUtils tokenUtils;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        authenticationTokenFilter = new AuthenticationTokenFilter(authenticationManager(), tokenUtils);

        http.csrf().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()//.antMatchers("/api/authenticate", "/admin/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilter, AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class).httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }
}
```

if i use @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) ApiSecurityConfiguration works perfectly and the first configuration get missed up,
and if i switched it to @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE) the first one works perfectly and ApiSecurityConfiguration get missed up and even the added filter is not activated anymore, I think they get conflicted with each other and one disable the other, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find any solution? (I'm having the same problem)

Comment: Me, too, pretty much exact same situation

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the antMatcher of both configurations, I mean that in both configurations antMatcher url must be unique. Ff you write different antMatcher urls then your problem should be solved